# Was able to insert a LTR word in RTL sentence in Word but when sentence length exceeds one line, everything gets shuffled again. How to fix this?

Tags: microsoft-word, language, microsoft-word-2013, unicode, input-languages

I was able to insert an English word in Arabic text on Word without shuffling the sentence parts [a recurring problem] by using the Unicodes specified in another answer in the stack overflow forum:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613613/why-words-are-shuffled-when-i-insert-english-words-in-any-arabic-urdu-persian-te

Example:

My name is Ghadir and in English it's written **Ghadir** and I don't know--

--وانا لا أعرف  Ghadir  اسمي غدير وبالانجليزية تكتب

But when I continue writing the sentence and it exceeds one line, everything gets shuffled.

Example [becomes]:

[1st line] My name is Ghadir **Ghadir** and I don't know how to deal with this text that doesn't get fixed [2nd line] and in English it's written

وأنا لا أعرف كيف يجب أن أتعامل مع هذا النص الذي لا يصلحGhadir اسمي غدير

وبالانجليزية تكتب

I have also noticed that I can add the English word in the Arabic text without using the unicodes, by relocating the cursor when writing - but the same shuffling problem happens when sentence exceeds a line.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am answering my own question but I am so happy I finally discovered what I was doing wrong:

When I used to write in Arabic, I never clicked the RTL thingy in the ribbon [circled in red], because I used to think that selecting the language I want to use [Arabic] and changing the paragraph alignment as shown in the figure [circled in green] was enough.

[turns out I can't upload figures yet so click on the link to see the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzNOD.png)

That was somehow enough when I didn't need to use English inside Arabic -- but when you need to do that, you have to click on the RTL option. Now the direction of your paragraph is RTL. And now when you type in [or insert] the Unicodes [the ones mentioned in the first answer to the question in the link I put above in the question details]- it will work beautifully.

For more information on what does it mean to assign your paragraph to RTL, and what each of the Unicodes actually do, go to the following link: 
http://dotancohen.com/howto/rtl_right_to_left.html#Directionality